# Is it possible to add a version number to oracle package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, .net-4.5

Is it possible/and how  to stamp a version number to a 11g Oracle Package. Preferably with a auto-incremented number each time Package is compiled. Also I need to extract the version of the package using Oracle Managed DataAccess assembly on net framework 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you need...

You can use SVN tag revision right after package specification. But revision number will be updated only when you submit into SVN. So you can use it to match version in SVN against version compiled on database.

You can also always get last modification time from :

```
select * 
  from user_objects
where object_type in ('PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY');
```

Comment: Rusty, I am not using any SVN. the package is compiled directly to the database, I see there is a 'Edition Name' column when I exec the query you posted. How do I pass a value to that when I compile ?

Comment: Edition is related to editions only. This is designed for migration purposes. I can have only 1 edition at the time. I don't thing that suites to you. Do you need to control versioning on the objects on the database?

Comment: I have open-source product - CORT which does version control for all database objects. Please visit www.softcraftltd.co.uk/cort to see details. You can also download it and test. If you have any further questions related to this product please email (there is email on the website)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST1
-- This is package TEST1 ver %1.1%
AS    
  ver VARCHAR2(128);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST1
AS    
BEGIN
  ver := '1.1';
END;
```

Then you can either extract version of the package by querying `<package name>.ver`. Or by searching for special pattern in DBA_SOURCE (the package header comment). You can also combine this with SVN propset.

If you want to do it "automagically", i.e. without any CVS or developers assistance (which I do not recommend) you can create special DDL trigger `AFTER DDL ON DATABASE`.